# Как сделать так, чтобы когда удалялся файл (при нажатии на кнопку удалить) удалялось или менялось фейковое имя на "Файл не выбран"?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как сделать так, чтобы когда удалялся файл (при нажатии на кнопку удалить) удалялось или менялось фейковое имя на "Файл не выбран" ?
Сделала форму отправки, стилизовала инпут, кнопку и сделала так же, фейковое имя файла, когда прикрепляю какой-нибудь файл, имя меняется на имя файла, все хорошо, но когда нажимаю на кнопку удалить, файл удаляется, но имя файла остается прежним, а нужно, чтобы оно пропало, а лучше, чтобы менялось на "Файл не выбран"
Подскажите кто-нибудь, пожалуйста

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('input[type="file"]').change(function(e) {
                var nameFile = e.target.files[0].name;
                $(".name-file").text(nameFile);
 
            });

             $('body').on('click','#delete',function() { 
                alert('Вы действительно хотите удалить файл?');
                $("#nameFile")[0].value = "";
            });

        });
```

```css
.file__options {
  display: flex;
}

.file__item {
  position: relative;
}

.name-file {
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 13px;
}

.file__delite {
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #E53535;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #E53535;
  display: inline;
  margin-bottom: 14px;
}

.file__delite:hover {
  color: #c82e2e;
  border-bottom: 1px solid  #c82e2e;
}

.file__btn  {
  border: 1px dashed rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.26);
  padding: 12px 183px;
  display: inline-flex;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  background: #363A4D;
  height: 43px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="file">
  <div class="file__options d-flex justify-content-between">
    <a href="#" class="name-file">Файл не выбран</a>
    <a class="file__delite" id="delete">
      Удалить фото 
    </a>    
  </div>
  <div class="file__item">
    <input id="nameFile" accept=".jpg, .png, .gif" type="file" name="image" class="file__input">
    <button class="file__btn">Загрузить фото товара</button>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: добавить в клик удаления `$(".name-file").text('Файл не выбран');`

Comment: Да, получилось, спасибо большое:)

Comment: Только вот если я захочу опять добавить файл, у меня остается "Файл не выбран"

Comment: Проблема решена, надо было вместо  $("#nameFile").value = ""; прописать $("#nameFile").val('');
Спасибо большое:)